# How to: Debug source code on your local machine outside your solution in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Does any one know how to debug source code that is on your local machine, but outside of your solution?

Can I configure this somewhere in solution properties pane?
[image]

I' ve read about symbols servers, but I need more help on this. to clearly understand...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: İ think you have to convert it to dll.

Comment: Without a PDB file (or equivalen debug info baked into the compiled code itself, if that would be possible) that map pieces of compiled code with some specific parts/lines of source code line(s), it's not possible. Do you have the matching PDB file for the compiled code (an assembly, i assume) and do the source files you have are the exact same version of the source files that have been used to compile/build the code in question? (See here for more info: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2017)